# equal width elements are not equal in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `ul`and I've set  the width of the `li` items equal to `.col-lg-4` width but it seems their are not equal.

I've created here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/J5aGV/1/embedded/result/) to illustrate exactly the problem which I'm having.
Any suggestions on how can I make the `li` item below the  the same width as `col-lg-4` above ?

You will notice in the fiddle that the right border of the first `li` is not equal with the margin of the above image.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and I have this markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 nopadding">
   <div class='tabs tabs_default'>

      <div id='tab-1'>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="member-image">             
          <img src="http://placehold.it/550x350" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          </div>

            <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="member-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, eius, nam, asperiores cupiditate adipisci totam illo dignissimos similique quas repellendus porro non dolorum explicabo beatae consectetur eos facere dolores dolore.
            </div>
         </div>
         </div>

      </div>



       <ul class='horizontal text-center'>
        <li class="item"><a href="#tab-1">Rembrandt</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#tab-2">Picasso</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#tab-3">Dali</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with your "no-padding" class.  The Bootstrap grid works by adding 15px of padding left and right to any columns.  This is what provides the consistent gutters and pulls the content away from the edges of the container.

When you nest a row inside of a column as you have done, the row margins of -15px left and right negate the padding and insure that everything lines up nicely. That's the beauty of the grid.

So, get rid of your no-padding and you'll see everything is nicely lined up.

EDIT:
I have just noticed that you're not using cols on the tabs too. If that's intentional, and you just want your image to 'line up' with the first tab, then you'd alternatively have to remove the padding from the column containing the image.